# Can't use yast to install software online -- tries to mount a CD

Tags: repository, suse, yast, zypper, sles

I cannot use `yast -i` or `zypper install` in SLES 10; it wants me to insert a SLES 10 SP3 CD, but I don't have one. What should I do?

```
localhost:~ # zypper install curl-devel
Restoring system sources...
Parsing metadata for SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 SP3...
Parsing RPM database...
Summary:
<install>   [S1:1][package]curl-devel-7.15.1-19.16.13.i586
<install>   [S1:1][package]libidn-devel-0.6.0-14.2.i586
<install>   [S1:1][package]openssl-devel-0.9.8a-18.36.i586
Continue? [y/n]: y
Downloading: [S1:1][package]libidn-devel-0.6.0-14.2.i586, 1.1 M(4.3 M unpacked)
Please insert media [Failed to mount cd:///?devices=/dev/hdb on : Mounting media failed
] # 1 and type 'y' to continue or 'n' to cancel the operation. [y/n]: y
Please insert media [Failed to mount cd:///?devices=/dev/hdb on : Mounting media failed
] # 1 and type 'y' to continue or 'n' to cancel the operation. [y/n]:
```

Answer (score 3):

Check your YAST repositories, [here](http://forums.opensuse.org/archives/sf-archives/archives-tips-tricks-tweaks/323317-yast-repositories.html) is a list of common ones. Remove any references to `cd://` in the repository source file.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have the media or a repository how did you install it?

You can download SLES 10 SP3 for free from [SUSE's website](http://download.novell.com/index.jsp?product_id=&search=Search&families=2658&version=26302&date_range=&date_start=23%20Mar%202012&date_end=23%20Mar%202012&keywords=&sort_by=&results_per_page=&x=34&y=4) That is a direct link to SUSE site with the SP3 disk available for download.

`suse.com --> services and support tab --> Download header --> Products --> use the top pull-down to select SUSE Linux Enterprise --> 2nd pull-down to select 10 SP3 --> follow the links to download with 60-day eval. subscription.`

The product will work forever but, you will only get new updates for 60-days (if you register)

Though if you have multiple repositories listed and you have the CD listed as top priority as `taspeotis` said you can simply remove the CD entry and it will work if you have the valid files on your hard disk and listed in the repo.

Once you download the CD you can either mount it up, copy the files to the hard drive and add a new repo, add them to an indexable location on a web server and add a `http` repo, `nfs` or any other approved method found in YaST.

However, if you download the disc that is not the same you installed from. Meaning if you installed from the CD version and download the DVD version the GPG keys won't match and you will get errors. There is an option to override and ignore. Or go through remove the old keys and key files and import the ones from the newly downloaded disk.